# Templating legacy html php javascript functions to MVC

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2, refactoring, smarty

We are in process from converting our 10 old system to something more manageable.

Most of the stuff we somehow managed to convert to a loose mvc zend 2 based system but there are few... monsters still lurking.
We, for example, have one function which is basically a giant html/php mess. Which is in base one page of order details bloated to max.

The code structure is like this

```
function(){

php alters 
php inserts

html code
php code
htm/js code
php code...
html snipets in php variables...
pick a nightmare....

x 5000 times  of 8000 lines of code

}
```

I know I know, kill it, burn it with fire... but we can't. And we have to clean it up step by step.

**The question is :**

Does someone have an idea How we can make it as a gradual process without breaking the damn thing every monthly release (scrum yaaay) and without killing our self in process??

We use smarty for generating html output and zend2  modules for controllers.

I was thinking including the whole god damn thing in a output buffer and pasting it in a smarty variable and gradually pull the php out of it.

Any input is more then welcome or any literature pointer on pulling spaghetti php /html apart (I found some documentation but they never handle templating)

Comment: There is no "general help" anyone can give. It is up to you to figure out your unique problem and the best solution to it. It greatly depends on the complexity of the specific code/task. Perhaps things can be pried apart little by little if the code allows. Perhaps rewriting and porting over features is the best approach, and if that takes 6 months to complete but is the only way to do it, then so be it and business needs to accept that. We can't tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this question is too broad, and there is no way that you could have a unique good answer. There is as much good answer as developer on earth. Each of them will propose an advice, a direction to go, but you may not choose to listen them and it will probably just assure you in your decisions you've made.

For me (and I am in a more complex position than you are). I made another application wich communicate with my old code. With a bridge between them. My old code continue to works as expected, and my new code add some functionalities or replace them if it's finished.

I advice you to isolate your old code from your new application because you don't know how many time the new code will be in developpement. You can't take the risk to break your production code with your new developpement or introduce new bugs.

I can continue, and talk about my experience, but it's not the purpose of StackOverflow, like I said your question is too broad.

**Edit :**
From comment I quote

> "I have few methods for refactoring, but they are kinda messy."

You get my point. For respecting standards, and avoid to introduce more mess in an application already messy, you have to dissociate your development. There is no miracle. It's like a new version of a Framework like Zend Framework 2. Why do we use semver ? Why do we use versionning, and Break compatibilities etc... We do use those concept because we can't refactor in a maintainable way a procedural application or an old architecture into a respectful OOP approach, design pattern, MVC and so on.

> and im only asking about general pointers

That's the definition of "Too broad".

But I agreee with you, it will take abouuut 5 years, even more... But you have a job !

Comment: We have 18,587 Files, 2,137 Folders 641 MB of php code... so making a new aplication would take abouuuut... 5 years... wich we dont have. So my question is more then resonable. and im only asking about general pointers. i have few methods for refactoring, but they are kinda messy.

Comment: @Sangoku i Edited my post

Comment: Yes i agree on you, but it is just not possible to refactore such complex aplication wich has over 4000 custom modules. you have to do it step by step, but not with a new aplication interface, it is just not fesable while you develop the new old version the old version is evolving and by that time you are stuck with a really outdated version of the old system. That is why we have to do it  on the fly by doing  test driven development.

Comment: @Sangoku I have the exactly same problem, that's why, since two years now, all new developments are made with the new application. And some of those development are able to replace old code. And we do it. You have luck your old code is in PHP. Mine is in a language that you can't find a trace on the web, because it's a language develop by a company wich not exist anymore and used very few times.